# How to persist a new customer row in Cassandra using Hector?

Tags: java, jsp, nosql, cassandra, hector

I have spent an entire day trying to insert data into a simple cassandra database for storing username, password, email and phone.
All research I have done keeps taking me back to http://hector-client.github.com/hector/build/html/content/getting_started.html#update. I have followed the examples to the letter but when I try to execute my code:

```
        ConfigurableConsistencyLevel ccl = new ConfigurableConsistencyLevel();
    Map<String, HConsistencyLevel> clm = new HashMap<String, HConsistencyLevel>();

    clm.put("customers", HConsistencyLevel.ONE);
    ccl.setReadCfConsistencyLevels(clm);
    ccl.setWriteCfConsistencyLevels(clm);
    Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("test-cluster", "localhost:9160");     

    Keyspace ksp = HFactory.createKeyspace("qualebs", cluster);
    ksp.setConsistencyLevelPolicy(ccl);

    ColumnFamilyTemplate<String, String> template = new ThriftColumnFamilyTemplate<String, String>(ksp, "customers", StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get());

    ColumnFamilyUpdater<String, String> updater = template.createUpdater("KeyIsUsername");
    updater.setString("name", "the name");
    updater.setString("email", "email@email.com");
    template.update(updater);
```

I get the following exception when trying to run my application:

```
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Not enough bytes to read value of component 0)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:20833)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:964)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:950)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:246)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl$3.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:104)
at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:258)
... 57 more
```

I need help with understanding the reason for this error.

My schema which I created from cqlsh terminal looks like

```
 CREATE TABLE customers(username text PRIMARY KEY, name text, email text);
```

Comment: Which Cassandra version are you using?  It looks like your key or column types are CompositeType but your thrift code is using UTF8Type.

Did you do any other schema changes?  Which CQL version did you create the table in?

Comment: sir thank you very much for your attention. I am using cassandra version 1.2.2 and I used CQL VERSION 3.0 which is included in the tar. I haven't altered the table. how do I specify these compositeType and utfType keys when doing an update from Hector

Comment: It shouldn't be a CompositeType with that definition.  Using a compound primary key will make the key CompositeType and could cause this problem - see http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/Inserting-via-thrift-interface-to-column-family-created-with-Compound-Key-via-cql3-td7585194.html.  You could try creating the column family through cassandra-cli if you are not going to use CQL to query it.

Comment: I've created columnFamily with the following command. wanna use username as the primary key how will i do it `create column family customers
 with comparator = UTF8Type
 and key_validation_class = UTF8Type
 and column_metadata = [
 
 {column_name: username, validation_class: UTF8Type}
 {column_name: name, validation_class: UTF8Type}
 {column_name: email, validation_class: UTF8Type}
 {column_name: phone, validation_class: UTF8Type}
 {column_name: sex, validation_class: UTF8Type}
 {column_name: password, validation_class: UTF8Type}
 {column_name: balance, validation_class: DecimalType}

];`

Comment: The primary key in cassandra-cli terms is the row key rather than a column.  So remove username from the column_metadata and try your code.

Comment: Good morning? I am now able to insert a row into the customers column family and it's all thanks to you. I decided to use `String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());` as my row key. But it just doesn't seem right. what if two users were signing up at exactly the same time or i lost the time setting, a subsequent user signing up overwrites an existing user who has the same row key. I want a way of generating auto incrementing unique ids.

Comment: You should use TimeUUIDs as your row key.  They are time ordered and (probabilistically) guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: are these supplied by the application or will cassandra generate them if I specify the row key to be of TimeUUID Type?

Comment: They are application supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be to try playOrm which does correct conversions for you AND creates the CF's for you as well so you don't need to worry about creating it wrong ;).  Just an option.

Get the framework via the [PlayOrm](http://buffalosw.com/products/playorm/) homepage or via [GitHub](https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm)